# Filter entries in CP by Author

Tags: control-panel, search, author

How can you filter entries in the CP by Author? I assumed entering something like **author:tdavis** (where tdavis is my username) would do it, but no results returned. I also tried substituting id for username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Search](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#searching-for-specific-element-attributes) page in the docs, it looks like you can't search by author.

It looks, on the face of it, like entries can only be searched on Title, Slug and any of your Custom Fields.

Answer (score 2):

For Craft 3, at least for now.

1. Make a custom plugin
2. Add event to modify the query in control panel

   ```
   // Register element query prepare event
   Event::on(ElementQuery::class, ElementQuery::EVENT_BEFORE_PREPARE,
       function(Event $event)  {
           if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsCpRequest()) {
               if ($event->sender->elementType === 'craft\elements\Entry') {

                   if(isset($_POST['criteria']['search'])&&strpos($_POST['criteria']['search'],'author')!==false)
                   {
                       $email = explode(':',$_POST['criteria']['search']);
                       if(isset($email[1]))
                       {
                           $user = User::find()->email($email[1])->one();

                           if($user)
                           {

                               $event->sender->query->andWhere(['authorId'=>$user->id]);  
                               $event->sender->subQuery->andWhere(['authorId'=>$user->id]);  
                               $event->sender->search = null;
                           } 
                       }

                   }
               }
           }
       }
   );
   ```
3. So when you type `author:[Email]` it can fetch in the CMS.